# how do I analyse this logcat error that is shown when my program crashes at startup?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

This is from the logcat:

```
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph/com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.SeekBar
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.SeekBar
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-23 17:48:00.288: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    ... 11 more
```

I have only posted the ones coded in red colour from the logcat. I have no idea why or how this happened. Worst of all, the program was compiling and working fine, but then I played around for a while on the GUI version of `activity_main.xml`, and suddenly the program starts crashing. The `Log.d()` codes that I had placed in the beginning of onCreate() seem to  be showing their error message in the logcat so I know the program is at least running upto that point. But why is it crashing after that? What does this logcat error mean?

Comment: show your code and the relevant xml you are casting button to a seekbar. you have a button probably in xml and while initializing button  you are casting it to seekbar and look at line `49 MainActivity.java`

Comment: Logcat is so nice with you: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.SeekBar at com.example.mybasicinteractivegraph.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)`

Comment: This is the code I have at line 49: `gainControl1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);` where `gainControl1` is a field of MainActivity class, declared as `SeekBar gainControl1, qControl1;`

Comment: seekbar1 is declared in the xml file as    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp" />

Comment: clean and build your project once

Comment: cleaning seems to work. Thank you very much. Is it possible to get a "clean current project" function in a single command button as in Visual Studio?